# Lie bracket of vector fields is a vector field

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

Let $X$ and $Y$ two vector field on the manifold $M$ (dim($M$)= $m$). Show that the Lie bracket $[X, Y] := XY - YX $ is a vector field on $M$.

I tried to compute using local coordinates, so for $X = \sum_{i=1}^{m} X_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ and $Y = \sum_{i=1}^{m} Y_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$ I obtain after computation that 
\begin{align}
[X, Y] = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{m} X_j \frac{\partial Y_i}{\partial x_j} - Y_j  \frac{\partial X_i}{\partial x_j} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}
\end{align}

But how can I conclude now that the Lie bracket $[X,Y]$ is a vector field on $M$?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a typical homework. See for example [here](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~cjtsai/teaching/14dg/HW10.pdf). So follow the hints given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything is smooth:

$\textbf{Lemma}.$  Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.  The map $D: C^{\infty}(M) \to C^{\infty}(M)$ is a derivation if and only if, $Df = Xf$ for some smooth vector field $X$.

In particular, this says that derivations of $C^{\infty}(M)$ can be identified with smooth vector fields.  So, it suffices to show that the Lie bracket is a derivation of $C^{\infty}(M)$.

$\textbf{Sketch.}$
$$
\begin{align*}
[X,Y](fg) &= X(Y(fg) - Y(X(fg)) \\
&= X(fYg + gYf) - Y(fXg + gXf) \\
&= \ldots
\end{align*}
$$